# Optimize query for orders with unseen comments

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mysql-5.5, query-performance

I have following MySQL tables in an application I have to support:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders
(
  id         int     auto_increment primary key,
  author     int(8)  not null,
  manager_id int(10) default 0 not null
);

CREATE TABLE order_items
(
  id            int(12)         auto_increment primary key,
  order_id      int             not null,
  amount        int(3)          not null,
  price         decimal(10, 2)  null
);

CREATE TABLE comments
(
  id            int(10)      auto_increment primary key,
  module        int(10)      not null,
  item_id       int(10)      not null,
  item_type     varchar(8)   not null,
  message       text         not null,
  author        int(10)      not null
);

CREATE TABLE comments_seen
(
  user_id    int(10) not null,
  comment_id int(10) not null,
);
```

Comments table is shared between chat, testimonials, order-level comments and order-item-level. Total order comments comprise of order-level and order-item-level comments, which can be JOIN'ed with `comments.module = 5 AND comments.item_id = orders.id` and `comments.module = 4 AND comments.item_id = order_items.id` respectively. If a comment was read by user (e.g. manager) then there's respective row in `comments_seen`, referencing comment id and user id.

**What would be the most performant query to list orders with unread comments?**

**I need to show a list of orders accessible to current user (e.g. order author or order manager), but only show orders with unread comments.**

**UPD1**: My current attempt is as following:

```sql
(
  select o.id
  from cart_orders o
  inner join comments c on
    (c.item_id = o.id and c.module = 5)
  left join comments_seen cs on cs.comment_id = c.id  and cs.user_id = 2
  group by o.id
  having sum(cs.comment_id is null and c.is_deleted is false) > 0
  order by o.add_date
)
union distinct
(
  select o.id
  from cart_orders o
    left join order_items oi on o.id = oi.order_id
    inner join comments c on
      (c.item_id = oi.cat_id and c.module = 4)
    left join comments_seen cs on cs.comment_id = c.id and cs.user_id = 2
  group by o.id
  having sum(cs.comment_id is null and c.is_deleted is false) > 0
  order by o.add_date
)
```

But that gives me a list of unique order ids, which either have unread order comments, or unread order item comments. Is there way to represent it in following manner:

```
+----------+----------------+--------------------+
| order_id | order_comments | orderitem_comments |
+----------+----------------+--------------------+
|        1 |              0 |                 10 |
|        2 |              4 |                  1 |
|        3 |             13 |                 25 |
|        4 |              2 |                  0 |
+----------+----------------+--------------------+
```

<s>The `NOT IN` seem not to perform well and I know there's a way to make it work with proper JOINs, but I just can't wrap my head around it.</s>

MySQL server version is 5.5.48.

Comment: Schematically: `SELECT user FROM (users INNER JOIN orders LEFT JOIN comments) WHERE (conditions) GROUP BY user HAVING COUNT(comment.seen IS NULL) > 0`

Comment: That seem to be quite similar to what I've already done before for another task: show list of managers with their unread comment in orders assigned to them. My task is a bit different now: select all orders accessible to current user but show only ones with unread comments. I'll update the question to state it more clearly.

Comment: *That seem to be quite similar* No/ You must count the number of summarized records which have no seen part (contains null added during left join). So you must have GROUP BY in the query and perform filtering in post-grouping HAVING section. I see neither GROUP BY nor HAVING in your query. No similarity.

Comment: You're right, I had to use group by and having, obviously. What I meant was that your hint was similar to some other task of mine, not directly related to this question. I have updated my current solution, but it's still not what I need