# Table design comment_seen vs comment_unseen — migrate data from one to another

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.5, migration, schema-migration

I have system that allows [comments posted by users and tracks which users seen which comments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233301/optimize-query-for-orders-with-unseen-comments).
The read/unread state is tracked within `comments_seen` table. Surely enough, it grow tremendously.

My goal is to move from `comments_seen` table to `comments_unseen`.
Read/Unread status is only tracked for comment author and users in admin group (eg. admins see all new comment on site and should react respectively, while users only see answers to their comments or comments to their orders).

Current `comments_seen` table is almost 36M rows, while it's current definition is as simple as

```sql
CREATE TABLE comments_seen
(
    user_id    int(10) NOT NULL,
    comment_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_id
        UNIQUE (user_id, comment_id)
)
```

The `comments_unseen` table could be very much the same.

What would be your suggestions on my steps to moving from one table design to another?
Any triggers to keep data consistent?
Any deployment/migration steps?
All queries in code could be rewritten at once, I guess, so time to support both tables can be minimized to, say, seconds or minutes.

The overall application load isn't very high and everything could be done in night times for most users to not affect performance or UX.
Any thought, suggestions and shared experience is very much appreciated.

The DB is MySQL 5.5

**UPDATE 2021-04-01**: As pointed out in comments 35M rows isn't huge, but the culprit must be the query.
So here's the slowest query (as reported by Percona's [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html)):

```sql
SELECT
            SUM(`is_deleted` IS NOT TRUE) AS `total_count`
            , SUM(`parent_id` = 0) AS `branch_count`
            , SUM(`parent_id` = 0 AND `is_can_answer`) AS `opened_branch_count`
            , SUM(`parent_id` = 0 AND NOT `is_can_answer`) AS `closed_branch_count`
            , SUM(`cs`.`comment_id` IS NULL AND `is_deleted` IS NOT TRUE) AS `new_count` , SUM(`cs`.`comment_id` IS NULL AND `is_deleted` IS NOT TRUE AND `module` = 5) AS `order_comment_count` , SUM(`cs`.`comment_id` IS NULL AND `is_deleted` IS NOT TRUE AND `module` = 4) AS `items_comment_count` 
        FROM (
                            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT
                                    5 AS `module`
                                    , 'm' AS `item_type`
                                    , `co`.`id` AS `item_id`
                                FROM `cart_orders` AS `co`
                                WHERE `co`.`author` = 65
                                OR `co`.`manager_id` = 65
                                
                            )
                            UNION
                            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT
                                    5 AS `module`
                                    , 'i' AS `item_type`
                                    , `pr`.`id` AS `item_id`
                                FROM `cart_orders` AS `co`
                                    JOIN `cart_package` AS `cp`
                                        ON `cp`.`order_id` = `co`.`id`
                                    JOIN `pictures_relations` AS `pr`
                                        ON `pr`.`module_id` = 5
                                            AND `pr`.`item_id` = `cp`.`id`
                                            AND `pr`.`item_type` = 'opkg'
                                            AND `pr`.`is_file` IS FALSE
                                WHERE `co`.`author` = 65
                                OR `co`.`manager_id` = 65
                                
                            )
                            UNION
                            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT
                                    4 AS `module`
                                    , 'm' AS `item_type`
                                    , `cat`.`id` AS `item_id`
                                FROM `catalog` AS `cat`
                                    INNER JOIN (
                                        `cart_positions` AS `cp`
                                        JOIN `cart_orders` AS `co`
                                            ON `cp`.`order_id` = `co`.`id`
                                    )
                                        ON `cp`.`cat_id` = `cat`.`id`
                                WHERE `co`.`author` = 65
                                OR `co`.`manager_id` = 65
                                
                            )
                            ) AS `source` JOIN `comments` AS `a` USING (`module`, `item_id`, `item_type`) 
            LEFT JOIN `comments_seen` AS `cs` ON `cs`.`comment_id` = `a`.`id` AND `cs`.`user_id` = 65 
        WHERE ((TRUE))
```

Execution time for the whole query, and it's `UNION`ed parts:

```
complete - 8s 451ms

1 - 775ms
2 - 1s 214ms
3 - 3s 623ms

2+3 - 4s 891ms
1+3 - 4s 314ms
1+2 - 1s 945ms
```

Clearly, there's only single `JOIN` by both `comment_id` and `user_id` columns, so the issue seem to be not in the `comments_seen` table as I initially thought, but rather in overall poor table design.

Comment: Surely a comment is either seen or unseen - then why have an unseen table? Just INSERT a record when the comment becomes seen? If it's not present in the table for  a given user, then it must be unseen - surely? And why are you not running a more recent version of MySQL? There's a shedload of new features in recent versions that make a dev's life way easier...

Comment: @Vérace comment can be seen by one user and unseen another user. But yeah, when comment has been seen it's inserted into table. But the table is huge now (35 millions rows) and still growing. This hits performance since finding unread comments for orders or order items or in chat is a dirty union.

Comment: Rename your `user_id` constraint to `comment_seen_u_idc_id_pk` and make it your PRIMARY KEY so that you know what you're looking at! How long is it taking to do a search on this table? Maybe with a UNIQUE index on comment_id_user_id might help speed up some searches? 35M records is **not** a hugely large table...

Comment: @Vérace Yes, the naming is quite confusing, I should rename the unique constraint. Regarding the primary key - `DESC comments_seen` shows that both columns are already considered to be part of primary key, although the CREATE TABLE statement taken from recent DB dump is exactly as provided in question.

Comment: Regarding the outdated version of MySQL — it's an old server and quite brittle one, I'm not very confident in upgrading DB server (although, if it's quite straightforward for 5.5 -> 5.6 upgrade I'm ready to take a shot).

Comment: I'm not sure a `comments_unseen` table will have any less rows (I'd actually expect the cartesian product of unseen comments x users to be a lot higher) unless the definition of an unseen comment in this context is one that is completely *new* / no user has seen it yet. In any case, searching 36 million rows in a table of only two integer fields should actually be rather fast, assuming your predicates always filter on the `user_id` field. As @Vérace pointed out, 36 million rows is not that huge, and the fact it's only two integer columns is rather small of a table actually. If your slow...

Comment: ...queries are filtering on just the `comment_id` column then you might see much better performance creating a separate index on just `comment_id` so that it's covered. Curious what your search queries currently look like and the average runtimes you're experiencing, as I'd expect the *search* part of your query's operations should take no more than a second or so itself. (Depending on how much data you're actually returning back to the client and that runtime is a different story though, e.g. if you were returning millions of rows to the client every time.)

Comment: Do take a shot in upgrading to 5.6; 5.5 is past End-Of-Life; 5.6 is on the verge of such.  Then come 5.7 and 5.8 to catch up.  The farther behind you are, the harder it is to catch up.

Answer (score 1):

(Addressing first question)

Toss `comment_unseen`; instead, use a `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL` or `WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM comment_seen WHERE ... )`

For `comment_seen`, replace

```
CONSTRAINT user_id UNIQUE (user_id, comment_id)
```

with this (Note: a PK includes a uniqueness constraint):

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, comment_id)
```

If you need to look up which users have seen a comment, add

```
INDEX(comment_id, user_id)
```

There is no need to also make that `UNIQUE`; in fact, there is some harm.

Comment: Doesn't `PRIMARY KEY` imply `INDEX` alongside with `UNIQUE` constraint?

Comment: @EduardSukharev - Yes.  PK is a unique, which is an INDEX.  FK also implies an index (on one side).  But, note that my INDEX has the columns in a different order; this is important for some queries.  Also, every table needs a PK.

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL` and `WHERE NOT EXISTS` trick sadly didn't help — returned data was way off

Comment: I thought every secondary index includes PK which makes the index you advised to create looks somewhat similar to (`comment_id`, `user_id`, PK(`user_id`, `comment_id`) ). Does it make sense to make it that complex?

Comment: @EduardSukharev - Since those two columns are already in the secondary index, nothing need be added.  The goal is for the leaf node of the secondary index's BTree to have all the columns of the PK, thereby letting it drill down the PK to find the rest of the columns in the data BTree.

Comment: @EduardSukharev - The order of the columns in any index matters.